# Android Firebase Analytics not working correcty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to track which button is clicked using Google Firebase Analytics.

Code I tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View view) {
    int btn_id = view.getId();
    if (view.getId() == R.id.Btn1) {
        //Some content
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.Btn2 {
        //Some content
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.Btn3) {
        //Some content
    }
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, String.valueOf(btn_id));
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("homebtn_event", params);
  }
}
```

The above code tracks clicks on buttons but does not returns **btn_id** or which button is clicked in Firebase Analytics data

Comment: Firebase events will be visible after 24 hours, Instead try debug mode of Firebase if you want to see if event works or not!

Answer (score 4):

*Firebase analytics event will be visible on Dashboard after 24 hours*

But

> You can enable verbose logging to monitor logging of events by the SDK
>   to help verify that events are being logged properly. This includes
>   both automatically and manually logged events.

You can enable verbose logging with a series of adb commands:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

> This command displays your events in the Android Studio logcat,
>   helping you immediately verify that events are being sent.

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Firebase Analytics doesn't automatically provide parameter reporting for custom events/parameters. You have two options to understand how your button is clicked:

1. You can [link the account to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query) and select the "homebtn_event" event with "homebtn_event" parameters of given value. BigQuery has free tier that should allow you to do this for free (assuming your app is not one of the major apps). This will give you a lot of flexibility to query the data.
2. You can use one of the predefined events + predefined parameter that has reporting in Firebase Analytics. You can use [SELECT_CONTENT(ITEM_ID)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#SELECT_CONTENT) for example:

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString(Param.ITEM_ID, String.valueOf(btn_id));
   bundle.putString(Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "button");
   mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

Answer (score -2):

You can try this :

```
  firebaseAnalytics = com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(c);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("homebtn_event",String.valueOf(btn_id));
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.Event.LOGIN, bundle);
    firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    Log.v("homebtn_event",String.valueOf(btn_id));
```

Comment: firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true); call is not needed. It will enable collection if it was disabled before that with another call to the function. Enabling collection after logging event will have no effect on the event. it only affects any subsequent events.